# list of tools used to do the Django development

Tags: python, django

I am new to Django and python. Please if you can help me in tools which are used for Django development work, it will be great help.

Thank you in Advance

Comment: Text editor. Fingers. Brain.

Comment: @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams Well commendable response. This question was asked in **interview** to me. So I brought up this question.

Comment: I *refuse* to believe that anyone could fail an interview on this question alone.

Comment: @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams  .. Well if a person cannot find answer on internet where is one suppose to put up their questions on. I think Stackoverflow is the forum for all such questions (not only technical questions). I am new into it and I posted a question does it mean I am give (-2) twice..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Personally as IDE I use Pycharm, it's just great, has really an extensive support for Django.

Besides I use Fabric for automated deployments.

Not sure if you ask exactly about that. In case you do not know Django contains itself a lot of "tooling commands" available via manage.py

Comment: thank you for your reply. I was asked about tool used with Django. I searched net and could not get much great answers on it. By your answer it seems they were asking about tools which are used with IDE. Thank you once again. Regards

Answer (score 1):

You just need Python and Django to work with Django.

To do it the right way, I'd highly recommend that you follow https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/intro/tutorial01/

After this, you'll have a good idea about how to work with Django.

Some other useful resources:

- http://www.tangowithdjango.com/book17/
- http://www.djangobook.com/en/2.0/index.html

For tools, any text editor will work. You don't need anything fancy.

I personally use Atom Text Editor for no particular reason.

Comment: Thank you too for replying. I started from tutorial you shared. Still learning. Thank you for your reply.